# How to initiate checkbox group values from number total

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, numbers

I have a group of checkboxes with the values `1,2,4,8,16,32,64`. Each number is representative of a day of the week respectively (e.g. Sunday, Monday etc...)

The checkbox group value is the sum of the selected checkboxes. Sun, Mon, Tue = 7.

I have not been able to come up with a function that can breakdown the sum back into the appropriate numbers for the correct checkboxes to be selected on edit.

(I cannot just change their values to strings- the back-end team set it up this way)

#### First Attempt

```
`initSpecificDays(){
    let specificDaysArr = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64];
    let daysTotal = 44;
    let selectedDays = specificDaysArr.map(num=>{
      return daysTotal / num;
    })
    console.log(selectedDays)
  }`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the given value by taking [bitwise AND `&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND) with a calculated value of one and the index with [`<<` left shift operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3C%3C_(Left_shift)).

If the result is truthy, then you got your day.

It works by looking at a bit and compares this bit.

> An example with `7` for `["Sun", "Mon", "Tue"]`
>
> ```
> index  left shift  decimal   binary   bitw &   decimal   binary  comment
> -----  ----------  -------  -------  --------  -------  -------  -------
>    0     1 << 0         1         1   7 &  1        1         1  take
>    1     1 << 1         2        10   7 &  2        2        10  take
>    2     1 << 2         4       100   7 &  4        4       100  take
>    3     1 << 3         8      1000   7 &  8        0         0
>    4     1 << 4        16     10000   7 & 16        0         0
>    5     1 << 5        32    100000   7 & 32        0         0
>    6     1 << 6        64   1000000   7 & 64        0         0
> ```

```js
const
    getDays = value => ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
        .filter((_, i) => value & 1 << i);

console.log(getDays(7));  // ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue"]
console.log(getDays(65)); // ["Sun", "Sat"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight variation of Nina's answer with more pictures to help the reader figure out what's going on at bits level.

### Prerequisites

Before starting, be aware that JavaScript can read bits thanks to the `0b` prefix, and try to get familiar with "and" (`&`) and "shift right" (`>>`) bitwise operators (drop a comment if you need help):

```
> | 0b1
< | 1
> | 0b111
< | 7
> | (7).toString(2)
< | "111"
> | 1 & 1
< | 1
> | 1 & 0
< | 0
> | (0b101 & 0b110).toString(2)
< | "100"
> | (0b100 >> 1).toString(2)
< | "10"
> | (0b100 >> 2).toString(2)
< | "1"
> | (0b100 >> 3).toString(2)
< | "0"
```

In the expression `L & R`, `L` is often called "bit map", and `R` is often called "bit mask". The bit map is a set of binary flags (0/1, off/on, false/true), and the bit mask is a selector:

```
  flags  |   0000111 |   0000111 |   0000111
& mask   | & 0000001 | & 0000011 | & 0100100
= subset | = 0000001 | = 0000011 | = 0000100
```

In a binary number, the first bit (bit 0) is the rightmost one. The rightmost bit is called "least significant bit" (LSB), the leftmost bit is called "most significant bit" (MSB):

```
> | 0b0000111 >> 0 & 1 // reads bit 0 (LSB)
< | 1
> | 0b0000111 >> 6 & 1 // reads bit 6 (MSB)
< | 0
```

### Encoding

Days code:

```
  SFTWTMS <---- read carefully
0b0000001 =  1 = Sunday
0b0000010 =  2 = Monday
0b0000100 =  4 = Tuesday
0b0001000 =  8 = Wednesday
0b0010000 = 16 = Thursday
0b0100000 = 32 = Friday
0b1000000 = 64 = Saturday
```

Bit map of the selected days:

```
    |     SFTWTMS |
  1 |   0b0000001 |   Sunday
+ 2 | + 0b0000010 | + Monday
+ 4 | + 0b0000100 | + Tuesday
= 7 | = 0b0000111 | = selection
```

Bit map of the selected days, rotated and annotated:

```
Sat 0 drop (bit 6) <---- MSB
Fri 0 drop (bit 5)
Thu 0 drop (bit 4)
Wed 0 drop (bit 3)
Tue 1 take (bit 2)
Mon 1 take (bit 1)
Sun 1 take (bit 0) <---- LSB
```

### Filtering

This algorithm reads the bit map from LSB to MSB:

```
for i in [0-6] do: take ith day if bitmap >> i & 1 equals 1
```

Long trace:

```
                   SFTWTMS |   S
0b0000111 >> 0 = 0b0000111 |   1
               & 0b0000001 | & 1
               = 0b0000001 | = 1 (take "Sun")
                         ^ |
                    SFTWTM |   M
0b0000111 >> 1 = 0b0000011 |   1
               & 0b0000001 | & 1
               = 0b0000001 | = 1 (take "Mon")
                         ^ |
                     SFTWT |   T
0b0000111 >> 2 = 0b0000001 |   1
               & 0b0000001 | & 1
               = 0b0000001 | = 1 (take "Tue")
                         ^ |
                      SFTW |   W
0b0000111 >> 3 = 0b0000000 |   0
               & 0b0000001 | & 1
               = 0b0000000 | = 0 (drop "Wed")
                         ^ |
                          ...
                 and so on until i = 6
```

Short trace:

```
0 | 0000111 SFTWTMS | take "Sun"
1 |  000011  SFTWTM | take "Mon"
2 |   00001   SFTWT | take "Tue"
3 |    0000    SFTW | drop "Wed"
4 |     000     SFT | drop "Thu"
5 |      00      SF | drop "Fri"
6 |       0       S | drop "Sat"
          ^       ^
```

### Example

Real world example:

```
> | Sun = 0b0000001
< | 1
> | Mon = 0b0000010
< | 2
> | Tue = 0b0000100
< | 4
> | bitmap = Sun + Mon + Tue
< | 7
> | days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
< | ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
> | days.filter((_, i) => bitmap >> i & 1)
< | ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue"]
```

Note that the bit map is equivalent to an array of booleans:

```
> | take = [true, true, true, false, false, false, false]
< | [true, true, true, false, false, false, false]
> | selection = []
< | []
> | for (i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  |   if (take[i]) selection.push(days[i]);
  | }
  | selection
< | ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue"]
```

And `bitmap >> i & 1` ("read the ith bit") is equivalent to `take[i]` ("read the ith element"):

```
> | for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  |   console.log(i, bitmap >> i & 1, take[i]);
  | }
  | 0 1 true
  | 1 1 true
  | 2 1 true
  | 3 0 false
  | ...
```

### Comparison

Nina's version is slightly different, indeed, I shift the bit *map* to the *right*, while Nina shifts the bit *mask* to the *left*, which returns different results:

```
Me   : (bitmap >> i) & 1
Nina : bitmap & (i << 1)
```

```
      | bit map     | & | bit mask
------|-------------|---|----------
 Me   | bitmap >> i | & | 1
 Nina | bitmap      | & | 1 << i
```

My own version returns always 0 or 1 (false/true, drop/take):

```
> | 0b0000111 >> 0 & 1 // = 0b0000111 & 0b0000001
< | 1
> | 0b0000111 >> 1 & 1 // = 0b0000011 & 0b0000001
< | 1
> | 0b0000111 >> 2 & 1 // = 0b0000001 & 0b0000001
< | 1
> | 0b0000111 >> 3 & 1 // = 0b0000000 & 0b0000001
< | 0
```

Nina's version returns the selected day (a truthy value, take) or 0 (a falsy value, drop):

```
> | 0b0000111 & 1 << 0 // = 0b0000111 & 0b0000001
< | 1
> | 0b0000111 & 1 << 1 // = 0b0000111 & 0b0000010
< | 2
> | 0b0000111 & 1 << 2 // = 0b0000111 & 0b0000100
< | 4
> | 0b0000111 & 1 << 3 // = 0b0000111 & 0b0001000
< | 0
```

This doesn't make a big difference in the context of the `filter` function, except that returning boolean values (0/1, false/true) sounds a bit more consistent. However, with Nina's version you can collect the selected checkboxes like so:

```
> | bitmap = 0b0000111
< | 7
> | checkboxes = []
< | []
> | for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  |   day = bitmap & 1 << i;
  |   if (day) checkboxes.push(day);
  | }
  | checkboxes
< | [1, 2, 4]
```